# How to optimize the N-Queen backtracking

Tags: c++, backtracking

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("damesah.in");
ofstream g("damesah.out");
int st[20], n,nrSol=0;
void afisare() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    g << st[i] << " ";
    }
g << "\n";
}
int valid(int k) {
for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i) {
    if (st[k] == st[i] || abs(st[k]-st[i]) == abs(k-i))
        return 0;
    }
return 1;
}
void BK(int k) {
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    st[k] = i;
    if (valid(k)) {
        if (k == n) {
            ++nrSol;
            if(nrSol == 1)
            afisare();
        }
        else
            BK(k + 1);
        }
     }
  }
 int main()
{
f >> n;
BK(1);
g << nrSol << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have made to solve the N-Queen problem using backtracking , if you do not know the problem , here it is : The N Queen is the problem of placing N chess queens on an N×N chessboard so that no two queens attack each other. A queen is attacking another one if they are on the same column, row or on the same diagonal.

If we insert 4, the output will show only the first solution, then the number of solutions on the second row :

```
2 4 1 3
2
```

I want to optimise this algorithm using one more array which will store the row the diagonal and the column used by the queen so the complexity of the validation will be O(1), but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: If the code works, this is more of a code review thing and as such might be better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes it works, I just need help at optimizing it.